# Cannot read property 'RNCamera' of undefined on android

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I have installed and configured react-native-camera this way :

```
npm install react-native-camera
```

added these to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WR
```

added this line missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' inside android/app/build.gradle

using this code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  View,
  Text,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera'

const PendingView = () => (
  <View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent:"center",
    alignItems: "center"
  }}
  >
    <Text style={{fontSize: 30, color: "red"}}>Loading...</Text>
  </View>
)

const App = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

  const takePicture = async (camera) => {
    try {
      const options = {quality: 0.9, base64: false}
      const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      setImage(data.uri)
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error)
    }
  };

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    {image ? (
      <View style={styles.preview}>
        <Text style={styles.camtext}>Here is your new profile pic</Text>
        <Image style={styles.clicked} source={{uri: image, width: '100%', height:'80%'}} />
        <Button
        title="CLick new Image"
        onPress={() => {
          setImage(null)
        }}
        ></Button>
      </View>
    ) : (
      <RNCamera
      style={styles.preview}
      type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
      captureAudio={false}
      flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
      androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
        title: "Permission to use camera",
        message: "longer text to use camera",
        buttonPositive: "OK",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel"
      }}
      androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
        title: "Permission to use audio",
        message: "longer text to use audio",
        buttonPositive: "OK",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel"
      }}
      >
        {({camera, status}) => {
          if(status !== 'READY') return <PendingView/>
          return(
            <View
            style={{
              flex: 0,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              justifyContent: "center"
            }}
            >
              <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.capture}
              onPress={() => takePicture(camera)}
              >
                <Text>SNAP</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          )
        }}
      </RNCamera>
    )}
    </View>
  )
}

export default App;

const styles  = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
    backgroundColor: "#0A79DF"
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  capture:{
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: "orange",
    padding: 20,
    alignSelf: "center",
    
  },
  camtext: {
    backgroundColor: "#3498DB",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    marginBottom: 10,
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    paddingVertical: 20,
    fontSize: 25
  },
  clicked: {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    borderRadius: 150
  }
})
```

getting this error

```
Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'., js engine: hermes
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:93612:41)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:85300:36)
    at profilePic(RootComponent) (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:89907:28)
 ERROR  Error: Requiring module "node_modules\react-native-camera\src\index.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'., js engine: hermes
    at App (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:93612:41)
    at RCTView
    at View
    at RCTView
    at View
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:85300:36)
    at profilePic(RootComponent) (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.profilepic&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:89907:28)
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'RNCamera' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in profilePic(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'RNCamera' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in App
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in profilePic(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

added this line missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' inside android/app/build.gradle

Comment: Error is located in the `node_modules/react-native-camera/src/RNCamera.js`, the component used in the library - **ViewPropTypes** is deprecated. Solution is [here](https://github.com/react-native-camera/react-native-camera/issues/3427#issue-1331596130). Btw, react-native-camera is not maintained anymore, please use [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. open your node_modules/react-native/index.js
2. search for get ViewPropTypes()
3. replace this code :

```
    get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {   
      invariant(
        false,
        'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
        "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",    );  
    }
```

to this:

```
get ViewPropTypes(): $FlowFixMe {
  console.warn(
    'ViewPropTypes has been removed from React Native. Migrate to ' +
    "ViewPropTypes exported from 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types'.",
  );
  return require('deprecated-react-native-prop-types')
}
```

Happy coding!